# I need help to find the Encoding or Encrypting fucntion

Tags: encryption, encoding, hash, cryptography, hex

Here I have an unknown function that encodes or encrypts input Hex data and gives us the output result in Hex. I want to guess what kind of encoding or encryption function is that! I tried to check several known methods but failed. I put three examples of input data and the results of that function for each.

This is a function as a black box and I don't know what is inside of that, just I'm sure this function works on frames of 16 bytes of data.

First Example :

```
Input Data :     2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D
Function Result: AF 2D CE 76 B2 80 29 40 97 F3 E3 61 76 AF CB FC
```

2nd Example :

```
Input Data :     5A 5A 5A 5A 5A 5A 5A 5A 5A 5A 5A 5A 5A 5A 5A 5A
Function Result: 3E CC 1C D5 30 8C 25 43 F6 26 35 FC 8E 1D 16 3A
```

3rd Example :

```
Input Data :     00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Function Result: 2D 80 A3 9F 59 0E C1 30 26 6A 04 4E DA 6E F7 7D
```

All of the above results were generated with the same function and different input data, so I just need to find that function here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't about programming, as comments to the answer show. Also, OP is convinced that they could, maybe with help, crack state-of-the-art cryptography, which is also not something that can be helped with.

Answer (score 1):

If it's anything that deserves the description "encryption", it would be impossible to figure out, since information-theoretically, it's basically necessary that the output of the function is uncorrelated to its input for all practical matters, and on expectations is completely uniform and uncorrelated to itself.

You see that pretty well in your last, all-0 input example: the function can't be anything linear or memory-less.

So. That leaves you with homework-style things that one could for historical reasons call "cipher", but for which the word "cryptography" makes me cringe a bit :)

Try to expand your all-zero input run until the sequence repeats. If it's actually a 16 bit-word stream cipher, the fact that it necessarily only has finite state means at some point it repeats. This would at least give you a size of the internal state. Maybe you can then try to start a cryptanalysis by trying to combine ciphertexts to different known plaintexts. Again, is this is properly designed, the space of (sequence length) × 2¹⁶ input blocks would be too large to crack, but you seem to be optimistic it's not :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply , actually this is the encryption or encoding function of a new virus named "0xxx" , this virus encode or encrypts each 16 byte of the infected files with this function . Now I'm going to find that function to recovery my files.

Comment: lol why would a virus use some bad encryption, when there's dozens of good, practically uncrackable encryptions out there. Your data is gone.

Comment: I don't know why but it encrypts more than 1TB of my files with this function , as I analysis the behavior of the virus , it just infected first 65536 byte of each file and change the file extension to .0xxx

Comment: I think it must be a simple function,  something that done with arithmetic and boolean operations because that will be too CPU intensive I'd that virus want to use the cryptographic functions for 1TB of files!

Comment: that is a fallacy, as nothing says all the 1TB need to be instantly encrypted, and also, for example, the encryption used for HTTPS connections is plenty good enough to be uncrackable with "usual" compute resources, while not even for a full 1Gb/s connection making cryptography the limiting factor.

Comment: I understand,  but the virus put a unique 16 byte hex ID in a text file beside of each infected file to tell the hostage about how must pay for the decoding . I hoped this that can help us to find the type of algorithm because of the length is 16 byte always . When I know the algorithm , I can try to reverse it to find a way , but at this step I just need to know which function my be used for this encryption or encoding.

Comment: give it up. 16 B is 128 bit, that's not a search space you can manage

Comment: Your unique id: 1A95A0D307624CFC8BC75960B498EAD6

Comment: cool. So, that tells you your data is gone.

Comment: I don't worry about my data , I just want to learn more about that algorithm and how I can find what may be inside a black box. learn how I can reverse a function to reach the algorithm.

Comment: you can't. This is with a very high probability proven cryptography.

Comment: (I admire your sense of self-confidence. But if you knew how to even approach cracking something like a 128-bit AES or a similar algorithm, you would be a world-class cryptographer, and even these say these days it's not feasible to attack state of the art algorithms, and not someone on the internet, insisting that you can somehow reverse this.)

Comment: Thanks, I fully understand what you say, I just shared this as a problem to let others guess about it. maybe they know an unknown algorithm to me. this will help me to check fewer options, when I find the algorithm I can use GPU computing to reverse the function. maybe this process failed but I hoped to learn new things.

Comment: seriously, you need to find something else to work on. "Others" don't have a way to crack state-of-the-art cryptography, either. Otherwise it would not be: state-of-the-art cryptography. You don't even seem to realize how absurd it is to ask this persistently!

Comment: (I'm leaving this answer and these comments to illustrate why I'm voting to close this question, but I will no further interact, this is all in vain.)